# How to reverse the properties of pscustomobject?

Tags: arrays, powershell, stack, reverse

Is it possible to reverse the properties of `[Pscustomobject]` ?

I have to setup resources in queue order. After testing is over , i have to teardown the resources in reverse order.

below is the sample code.

```
$volume= @{Name='Vol1';size = "100gb"}
$VolumeCollection = @{Name = 'VolColl'; Volume = $volume}
$ResourceQueue = [pscustomobject]@{
    Volume = $Volume
    VolumeCollection = $VolumeCollection
}

function SEtup-Resources
{
    param
    (
        [psobject]$resource
    )

    $resource.PSObject.Properties | foreach-object {
        switch ($_.name) {
            "volume" { 
                "Volume is created"
            }
            "VolumeCollection" {
                "volcoll is created"
            }
        }
    }
}

function TearDown-Resources
{
    param
    (
        [psobject]$resource
    )

    # I have to reverse the object properties

    $resource.PSObject.Properties | foreach-object {
        switch ($_.name) {
            "volume" { 
                "Volume is deleted"
            }
            "VolumeCollection" {
                "volcoll is deleted"
            }
        }
    }
}

Write-host "-------------------------"
Write-host "Setup resources"
Write-host "-------------------------"
SEtup-Resources -resource $ResourceQueue

Write-host "-------------------------"
Write-host "teardown resources"
Write-host "-------------------------"
TearDown-Resources -resource $ResourceQueue
```

The result should be

```
-------------------------
Setup resources
-------------------------
Volume is created
volcoll is created
-------------------------
teardown resources
-------------------------
volcoll is deleted
volume is deleted
```

But i could not find the way to reverse the properties of an object. How to reverse the pscustomobject properties in powershell?

Comment: `function reverse { $a = @($input); [array]::reverse($a); $a }`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to alter order of few properties, you could just list them manually to `Select-Object`:

```
$ResourceQueue | Select-Object VolumeCollection, Volume
```

For more generic solution one could use `Get-Member`to get an array of properties, use `[Array]::reverse` to reverse 
order and then `Select-Object` to get the properties in desired order. I came out with this:

```
$props = @()
$MyObject | Get-Member | ForEach-Object { $props += $_.name }
[Array]::Reverse($props)
$MyObject | Select-Object $props
```

Comment: Why using `Invoke-Expression`? Is `$MyObject | Select-Object $props` not enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
$object = '' | select PropertyA, PropertyB, PropertyC
$object.PropertyA = 1234
$object.PropertyB = 'abcd'
$object.PropertyC = 'xyz'
$properties = ($object | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name
[Array]::Reverse($properties)
$object | select $properties
```

The result is

```
PropertyC PropertyB PropertyA
--------- --------- ---------
xyz       abcd           1234
```